# How to access the auto incremented id from a database seed?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am very new to Laravel and I am trying to seed something into the database.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'john@doe.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
            'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
}
```

That successfully creates an user with an auto-incremented `id`.

I now want to seed another table called `user_settings`. It's `user_id` has to be the same as the auto-incremented id of the inserted user.

```
DB::table('user_settings')->insert([
    'user_id' => // This has to be the auto-incremented ID of the earlier inserted user.
]);
```

How can I access the `id` that has been given to the user here, so that I can seed this in the `user_id` of `user_settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nifty method available in Query Builder class, `insertGetId()`, works normally  like an `insert()` method, but unlike `insert()`,  `insertGetId()` would return the auto-Incremented id.

```
public function run()
    {
        $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
              'name' => 'John Doe',
              'email' => 'john@doe.com',
              'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
              'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
              'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
           ]);

    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, and I think it is the best answer to the question. Personally I went with @Martin's answer though, because it might be useful to have in the future.

Comment: Martin's answer is perfect for Eloquent, i use it as well for Eloquent, since it would return the object that was inserted and you can access its values,

Answer (score 1):

Usually the approach i have seen, working on multiple projects would be to do something similar to this.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

$setting = factory(UserSettings::class)->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

This approach requires you to make [Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding), which should be straight forward and this is pretty clean. Meanwhile also being a more flexible way of doing it. You can easily create multiple users.

```
$users = factory(User::class, 10)->create(); //creates 10 users
```

Comment: Thank you, I just learned about factories and successfully implemented it. It works.

Comment: Super glad i could help, remember to accept it as an answer if it helped you get the task finished.

Comment: I accepted another answer that I think answers the question better. Your answer also answers it, but not as direct. Hopefully you understand. Still a +1, and I went with your solution.